# Prime Factors in C++(Error in program)

Tags: c++

- When I input `6` I only get `2`.
- When I input `91` I only get only `7`.

However:

- When I input `18` I get `2 3 3`.
- When I input `2121` (which is 3*7*101) I get `3 7`.

I can't seem to find what is wrong. Does anybody have any suggestions?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool is_prime( int fac )
{
    int i;
    bool found;
    found=true;

    for( i = 2; i < fac; i++ )
    {
        if ( fac % i == 0 && found)
        {
            found=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

void prime_factors(int x)
{
    int i;
    for ( i = 2; i < x; i++ )
    {
        if ( is_prime(i) )
        {
            while ( x % i == 0 )
            {
                cout << i << " ";
                x = x / i;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    prime_factors(x);
}
```

Comment: Gross, please align your lines and indent properly ...

Comment: You should be able to get your problem by debugging the case of input 6.

Comment: Sorry I didn't.I am new to programming.I'll take care to indent since the next time.Thanks!:)

Comment: @BhaveshThakkar Not next time, edit and indent the code in this question!

Comment: ‘*Does anybody have any suggestions?*’ Yes: Use a debugger.

Comment: Programming is about trying things out.  Step through it with a debugger. What's happening? What's working and what's not working? What's right and where does it go wrong?   Try it! Not next time.  Now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside of the code indentation woes (I fixed those for you), there are two major things wrong here:

1. You're modifying `x` within your `prime_factors()` function, and your loop tests against `x` to know when to exit early. You should make a copy of `x` so that you don't do this.
2. You're not restoring `x` between loops.

You can also cut the number of tests you're doing in half in your `is_prime()` function.

**Corrected Code Listing**

---

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool is_prime( int fac )
{
    int i;
    bool found = true;

    for( i = 2; i < fac; i++)
    {
        if ( fac % i == 0 )
        {
            found=false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

void prime_factors( int x )
{
    int i;
    int test;
    for ( i = 2; i <= x; i++ )
    {
        test = x;
        if ( is_prime(i) )
        {
            while ( test % i == 0 )
            {
                cout << i << " ";
                test /= i;
            }
        }
    }
}


int main(){
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    prime_factors(x);
}
```

---

**Sample Output**

---

```
./a.out 
100000
2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 5 

./a.out 
6
2 3 

./a.out 
1001
7 11 13
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know much about indenting.But I'll look it up and  indent my code so that it does not become cumbersome to read the code.

Comment: @BhaveshThakkar Look into a text editor that has things like auto-indentation, syntax highlighting, etc. VI/VIM is complicated as hell, but fun and useful to learn. Most modern IDEs have indentation assistance as a common feature.

Comment: Okay.I'll go with VIM.Thanks:)

Comment: And for cutting my tests into  half shouldn't is use i<(n/2) +1 in my is_prime() function?

Comment: Yep. Along those lines. Keep in mind, the algorithm you're using takes ages to run on a powerful PC just to calculate the prime factors of one-million. If you need to do larger numbers, you'll need to use a combination of "prime number sieves" an an arbitrary precision library (ie: big num library).